# Why TextView dont get updated with value from SharedPreferances?

Tags: java, android, textview, sharedpreferences

I have an issue updateing TextView in Android App.What I do is, when "+" button is pressed, RecycleView opens, then I click on the item retrived there from Kinvey.Then I pass name of the item Clicked to the Main activity.From Main activity i can LOG that data when I run the app for the seckond time (First time value is null since i did not clicked an item in RecycleView), but I can not set TextView with that Value(TextView stay empty)?3rd time when i run the app, retrived value is null again.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Testiraj";
    private RecyclerView rv;
    public Context context;
    private TextView TextViewGymName;
    private TextView TextViewVisitorsNumber;
    private List<AllGyms> mVisitors;
    public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public String mRVPickedItem;
    public String restoredText;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        TextViewGymName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gymName);
        TextViewVisitorsNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gymVisitors);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME,      MODE_PRIVATE);
        restoredText = prefs.getString("name", "nothing");


        if(restoredText!=null){
            Log.v(TAG,restoredText);
            TextViewGymName.setText(restoredText);



        }
        else{
            Log.v(TAG, "null" +" "+ restoredText);
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

        Intent intenti=getIntent();
        Bundle b = intenti.getExtras();





        if(b!=null){
            mRVPickedItem = (String) b.get("NAME_OF_THE_STRING");


            final Client mKinveyClient = new Client.Builder("KEY", "KEY_APP"
                    , this.getApplicationContext()).build();

            final Query query = new Query();
            query.equals("name", mRVPickedItem);
            query.equals("visitors");
            AsyncAppData<AllGyms> searchedEvents = mKinveyClient.appData("allGyms", AllGyms.class);
            searchedEvents.get(query, new KinveyListCallback<AllGyms>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AllGyms[] event) {

                    ArrayList<AllGyms> arrayList = new ArrayList<AllGyms>(Arrays.asList(event));
                    String[] array = new String[arrayList.size()];
                    mVisitors = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                        array[i] = arrayList.get(i).getVisitors();


                        //allGymses.add(new AllGyms(test[i].getName()));


                        //Log.v(TAG, "received " + array[i]);
                        TextViewVisitorsNumber.setText(array[i]);


                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to query ", error);
                }
            });





        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("name", mRVPickedItem);
        editor.apply();



        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        restoredText = prefs.getString("name", mRVPickedItem);
        TextViewGymName.setText(restoredText);

FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {




Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,       `RecyclerViewActivity.class);`
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });





    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  // Always call the superclass method first



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is  present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    }
```

RecycleView Activity:

```
package com.fittoloc.uros.gymloced;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;


import com.kinvey.android.AsyncAppData;
import com.kinvey.android.Client;
import com.kinvey.android.callback.KinveyListCallback;
import com.kinvey.android.callback.KinveyUserCallback;
import com.kinvey.java.Query;
import com.kinvey.java.User;
import com.kinvey.java.core.KinveyClientCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<AllGyms> allGymses;
private RecyclerView rv;
public Context context;

private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);






    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);



    rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);



    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);

    initializeRecycleView();





    rv.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new     RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {







                }
            })
    );





}


private void initializeRecycleView() {
    //ovde resiti problem!!!!
    final Client mKinveyClient = new Client.Builder("KEY", "KEY"
            , this.getApplicationContext()).build();

    mKinveyClient.user().login(new KinveyUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            CharSequence text = "Login error.";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(User u) {
            CharSequence text = "Welcome back!";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    final AllGyms teretane = new AllGyms();
    Query myQuery = mKinveyClient.query();
    myQuery.equals ("name");
    AsyncAppData<AllGyms> myGyms = mKinveyClient.appData("allGyms", AllGyms.class);
    myGyms.get(myQuery, new KinveyListCallback<AllGyms>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AllGyms[] results) {

            ArrayList <AllGyms> arrayList =  new ArrayList<AllGyms>(Arrays.asList(results));
            String [] array = new String[arrayList.size()];
            allGymses = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i = 0 ; i < arrayList.size() ; i++){
                array[i] = arrayList.get(i).getName();


                //allGymses.add(new AllGyms(test[i].getName()));
                allGymses.add((new AllGyms(array[i])));




                //Log.v(TAG, "received " + array[i]);
                initializeAdapter();


            }

            //Log.v(TAG, "received " + results + " allGyms");






        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "failed to fetchByFilterCriteria", error);
        }
    });


//


}







private void initializeAdapter(){
    RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(allGymses,context);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}



}
```

RecyleItemClickListener:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements         RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
        private OnItemClickListener mListener;
        private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
        private String position;


        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        }

        GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

        public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context,     OnItemClickListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
            mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
            View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }
```

Comment: use listener for this task...!!

Comment: Ok, i tried to find simple example of SharedPreferences Listener but with no luck.I still don't understand where to call it (OnResume, after of before I store the data in Preferences)?Can you help me with this?If not, thanks anyway since you pointed me out to the right direction. :-)

Comment: share complete with RecycleView code..

Comment: Check the edited Q. :-)